# Question about question about finite order elements at $\mathbb{C}^*/U$

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, normal-subgroups

At this question - [What are element with finite order at $\mathbb{C}^*/U$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612767/what-are-element-with-finite-order-at-mathbbc-u/612811?noredirect=1#612811) I understand that finite order at $\mathbb{C}^*/U$ are only the $e$ elements.
Now, I have two questions:

1. It is because $\frac{\Bbb C^\times}{U}\simeq\Bbb R^{>0}$? and $\Bbb R^{>0}$ has only one finite order element $1$, I'm right? (The first answer). And this is why $\mathbb{C}^*/U$ have only one finite order element $e$?
2. At $U$, the circle unit, the $e$ elements are only $z\in  \Bbb{C}$ that $|z|=1$, i.e. points at the unit circle s.t. $r=1$. I'm right here to or I miss something?

I hope I understand it correct, if not, please tell me what I miss,
And if you can help me to write the proof for it, becuase I don't know where to start...
Thank you!

I add something that might help me a lot: How those an element looks like at $\mathbb{C}^*/U$? maybe it could help a lot...

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou, I'm little bit confuse...LOL...

Comment: You got it all right. \o/

Comment: "$\,e\,$ elements"? WHat's that?

Comment: if $a\in G\;and \;|G|=n$ so $a^0=e,a^n=e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another, perhaps simpler, approach:

$$(cU)^n=U\iff c^n\in U\iff |c^n|=|c|^n=1\iff |c|=1\iff c\in U\ldots$$

and thus $\;\Bbb C^*/U\;$ is torsion free, and you don't need to know $\;\Bbb C^*/U\cong\Bbb R^+\;$ .

Comment: But if you saw my Q at the link that I gave, I need to find the finite order elements of $\Bbb C^*/U$ and prove it, I don'e see how your proof helps me... If you can explain little more it will be great.... Thank you!

Comment: If you can I'll be glad if you will write at $\Bbb C^*/U$, it will help me a lot!! thank you!!

Comment: I don't understand you, @YoavFridman: I **did** prove that the only element of finite order in the quotient group is the unit one...if you have problems understanding that you can write back in hebrew, if that makes things easier for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm understanding, I miss very important word at my comment: "element", at the next comment I'll write you the comment as it should be... Thank you and sorry...

Comment: If you can I'll be glad if you will write how **element** at $\Bbb C^*/U$ looks like , it will help me a lot!! thank you!!

Comment: I wrote it, Yoav: an element in $\;\Bbb C^*/U\;$ is a coset of the form $\;cU\;,\;\;c\in\Bbb C^*\;$ . That's why I began my answer as I did.

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you!